# Vue Router, refresh shows blank page

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter, state-management

Im trying to figure out why Vue.js routing, after I refresh my admin page re-directs back to the home component, only showing a blank page, and after a second refresh shows the home component again. I am still logged in as I can still go directly with the url to my admin-page. Meaning the session is still active. Is there a way to force the page to stay on the admin home page when I press F5? I tried things like history mode etc, but cant figure it out.

This is my router.js layout in the root and alos my main router file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import Home from './views/user/Home.vue'
import adminRoute from "./components/routes/admin-routes";

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/',
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false,
      }
    },
      ...adminRoute
  ],
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(r => r.meta.requiresAuth === false)) {
    next()
  } else if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    next(false)
  } else {
    next()
  }
});

export default router
```

and I have my admin-routes.js

```
    import AdminHome from "../../views/admin/AdminHome";
    import Users from "../../views/admin/Users";

    const adminRoute = [
        {
            path: '/admin-home',
            name: 'AdminHome',
            component: AdminHome,
            meta: {
              requiresAuth: true
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/users',
            name: 'Users',
            component: Users,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
            }
        }
    ];

export default adminRoute;
```

I do want to mention that my main page is under views/user/Home.vue and my AdminHome page is views/admin/AdminHome.vue

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for this as I'm having the same issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did yes. My original approach to this was wrong though. I will have a look and see what I did and let you know. If you have not found an answer to your issue yet.

Comment: What was the solution please

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? I get a black page when I hot the browsers refresh button. Would appreciate if you shared your fix.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is return to the **server** not the **built app**
you have to manage your 404 not found root
[Here you can find the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977676/error-404-on-reload-or-direct-url-with-vue-and-apache?fbclid=IwAR07LAwLUs3aq9CNpN7h2PTYoJ7LhRbLIAxcYvrvTp9feIzhpQ_zUBjXaqY)

and if you work With Netlify you just create a file in the root of the project ( same place as package.json) name netlify.toml containing

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

in vue4 they did away with the 'next' argument([see here](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)), this is working for me to send people back to the login page, where I'm using firebaseui, I have a simple boolean flag in my vuex store named "isAuthenticated" that I flip on when a user signs on.

> NOTE:  the following is a boot file for quasar v2 but the logic will
> work where ever you have access to the store

```
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default ({ app, router, store }) => {
    console.log('nav.js:')
    const isAuthenticated = computed(() => store.state.auth.isAuthenticated)
    console.log('isAuthenticated',isAuthenticated.value)
    router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
        console.log('nav.js:beforeEach:to',to)
        console.log('nav.js:beforeEach:from',from)
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
            if (!isAuthenticated.value) {
                console.log('nav.js:beforeEach:to.redirect')
                return '/login'
            }
        }
    })
    
}
```