# When following the link of the project to vue 3, the error is: Not Found (The requested URL was not found on this server.)

Tags: apache, deployment, vuejs3

There is a project written in vue 3. When you go to the page through the router-link, there are no problems, but if you knock on the route directly through the url line, it gives an error: Not Found (The requested URL was not found on this server.)

> Apache/2.4.53

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import Main from '../views/Main'
import Users from '../views/Users'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Main
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    name: 'users',
    component: Users
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 404 on reload or direct URL with Vue and Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977676/error-404-on-reload-or-direct-url-with-vue-and-apache)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like your web server isn't configured to serve the `index.html` of you Vue app also on errors like 404. You should set it up via `ErrorDocument` or `FallbackResource`.

Comment: If it's not difficult, please tell me the configuration for solving this problem.

Comment: @ПавелСаенко As shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735852/3975480